# Making letters bold without increasing their inside dimensions in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text

I'm looking to make some letters bold.
To achieve this I'm using the command 'Offset Path'.

The problem is that the inside of the letters becomes smaller.
Look at the image attached - the triangle inside the first 'A' (to which I applied the Offset Path) is smaller than the triangle inside the second 'A'.

Is there a way to make text bolder preserving the inside dimensions of the letters in Illustrator?

Thank you

[image]

Comment: You *do* realize how odd letterforms will look with large counters and only weight added to the outside, don't you?

Answer (score 2):

This is an obscure wish, but more obscure questions have got answers...so, the process can be automated only with some ultra clever custom software or by having a font which has inbuilt the wanted variation. If you don't have them you must tinker it manually letter by letter. You must edit the text as outlined curves.

[image]

1. Outlined text
2. Offset path is inserted
3. A couple of guard lines are drawn (=red) to mark the imagined interior area between the legs. They are drawn on the edges and stretched by dragging. With more complex fonts this needs excellent curve editing skills, it's easy only with straight lines.
4. The new glyph areas are filled with the Shape Builder. I used blue to show the filled areas.
5. The extras are deleted Use Shape Builder and hold Alt key at the same time for deleting.
6. The original for a comparison.

For me it doesn't look bolder, but bigger.

In theory you can make a modified version of a font in a font editor program, but you can knock your head to legal problems. Fonts are computer software which have copyright. Very likely you have no right to make own versions except in case it's explicitly allowed in the license.